# Text cursor disappears in Firefox

Tags: firefox, cursor

When using Firefox, sometimes the cursor will disappear, for reasons unknown. Note that I am referring to only the text entry cursor, not the mouse pointer. This makes it almost impossible to interact with text boxes and similar controls.

My Firefox version is 33.0, but I have also seen it in earlier versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old issue in Firefox, see bug reports [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=226301) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720233).

As a workaround, if you minimize and restore the Firefox window, the cursor will return.

Comment: Sadly the first bug remains unfixed even now.